# Worth going from R49 to R60 in attic?

Tags: insulation

We have about 3" of old insulation in our attic. We want to bring it up to R49 but I have read that some suggest taking it to R60 to get more energy efficiency. This may not be a question that can be answered without seeing the attic, but would the extra few hundred dollar be worth the energy saving benefits? The attic is already air sealed as well. Thanks for any insight.

Comment: How is the attic air sealed? I hope you mean the attic to living space is air sealed because the attic needs vents

Comment: You'd want to tell us what climate zone you're in. Without knowing that there's no confident answer.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is **it matters, barely.**

Beyond R25 in most climates has very very diminishing returns.  Having air seal to the house and air flow in the attic is way more important than adding more insulation.

I don't want to get into a diatribe but thermal mass (think weight of your building) is a much better indicator of energy savings than insulation.   Adding insulation on normal wood framed homes allows heat (or cold) to store in the insulation thereby negating the effectiveness beyond the "blocking".

You can use a [calculator](https://cellulose.org/Cellulose-Insulation-2nd.php?pagename=CalculateSavings&dirname=HomeOwners) to do the numbers and for a 1000 sq ft house you are looking at around $7-10 a year... and remember this calculator does not account for the mass of your home (or lack of) and it is actually created by the insulation industry - so they are going to use the lab numbers that suit them best.

When insulating your attic - taking other things out - there are three main things:

1. Don't expose wood that touches the house - wood is really a poor insulator so cover it.
2. There has to be a thermal break.   So is there a defined area of a few inches that covers everything from everything touching your "ceiling".
3. Does the quantity ensure if there are low spots that there is still proper coverage.

Look at the picture below.   Once you get to the "R40ish" stage, yes more is better, but does it have any sort of lasting effect?   No.

[image]

Comment: I would say going from ~r19 to R49 would be a good idea in many cases, but I agree proper ventilation can have a huge affect in the summer an attic fan can save more than the insulation or that has been my experience with my last 4 houses.

Comment: @EdBeal - when we talk about insulation and green topics on this site I think it is a good idea in general to move away from the "more insulation is better" conversation.   Yes it is but it does only matter to a point and the other stuff (ventilation, sealing, air flow in general, and yes thermal mass) is more important.   Any yahoo can walk around and attic and cover it with blown in cellulose.   If people are expecting vastly different or even slightly different utility bills, I doubt it with just more insulation past R40ish.

Comment: Although I agree with you a majority of homes in the US are stick built , some times with a brick veneer not a lot of mass, I have seen the largest reductions in my power bills with simple attic fans preventing the space from reaching 120-140f  with moderate r30-40 range insulation in the summer and the fan turned off in the winter. So may be we are saying the same thing not a lot of payback for an extra foot of insulation compared to a fan.

Answer (score 0):

Since I don't have your house handy, here's mine.

Cooling is negligible in my climate, so just looking at heating costs. Your climate may vary, as will the size of your house and the cost of your chosen heating fuel and/or electricity to cool, if needed.

3" is roughly R11 for typical old attic insulation types (you didn't specify 3" of what)

Cold-climate Heat pump annual cost savings estimate:

- Change R11 to R49 $249
- Change R49 to R60 $13

Electric resistance (the most expensive way to heat and not one I'm choosing) annual cost savings estimate:

- Change R11 to R49 $819
- Change R49 to R60 $43

You'll commonly git a bit **more** of a bump from moving up from 3" of insulation in practice, because that 3" is presumably leaving wood framing exposed between the insulation, and the first layer of insulation that covers the wood framing has more of an effect since its breaks the wood framing path (R3-6) as a heat leak.

Comment: Did you see what kind of "average" house the calculator was using as a baseline?    I say this because these insulation calculators often use a building with 2-4 times the normal thermal mass of stick/frame buildings we have in the US.   The energy savings for an increase in R value is much more consistent the higher the thermal mass.   Meaning with a lower thermal mass - as I mentioned in my answer - you are storing the heat or cold in the insulation, because it has no building to store it in.   Meaning it flat lines at a certain point, faster.

Comment: I'm not using your calculator link. I'm using the model for my house as based on the AgEngineering course where I learned the guts of HVAC calculations. It's purely heat-flow based.

Answer (score 0):

Let’s talk about thermal bridging...

I consult on passive house-like insulation values in colder climates, but I work in hot desert climates as well We do R80 in attics, R50 in walls and so forth. My clients - even in winter - barely turn their heat on.

Insulation is all for naught if you're not air sealing nor adding outboard insulation on exterior continuously, which takes care of thermal bridging!

Comment: This answer would benefit from clarification and references. I will try to fix some spelling and formatting but I don't want to make huge sweeping changes for fear of losing your intent. Please take the [tour] and then [edit] this post to do some additional clean-up and polishing.

Comment: I wouldn't say "for naught" -- but yes, there are limits on how far it can go, and next time you re-side you might want to look at adding a complete thermal layer. Meanwhile air-sealung is probably the single biggest bang for the buck in most stick-built houses,  and insulating the space above the top living floor might come next.